# How to warp design onto a packaging outline?

Tags: printing, packaging, adobe-illustrator

I have a design that I need to put on a cup. The design will wrap onto the cup, but I can't seem to do it in illustrator. I tried the warp function but it distorts the design a lot. Is there a way to do it so its not distorted or reverse-warp the outline ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW7Kz.jpg)

Comment: Try to ask here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is not about programming or scripting